# Attribute error: 'int' object has no attribute

Tags: python

```py
def make_dashboard(x, gdp_change, unemployment, title, file_name):
    output_file(file_name)
    p = figure(title=title, x_axis_label='year', y_axis_label='%')
    p.line(x.squeeze(), gdp_change.squeeze(), color="firebrick", line_width=4, legend="% GDP change")
    p.line(x.squeeze(), unemployment.squeeze(), line_width=4, legend="% unemployed")
    show(p)

make_dashboard(x=1952, gdp_change=6.0, unemployment=3.025000, title='dashboard', file_name='index.html')
```

I get this error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-60-b89657d5e9d6> in <module>
      1 # Fill up the parameters in the following function:
----> 2 make_dashboard(x=1952, gdp_change=6.0, unemployment=3.025000, title='dashboard', file_name='index.html')

<ipython-input-55-93fed9a96764> in make_dashboard(x, gdp_change, unemployment, title, file_name)
      2     output_file(file_name)
      3     p = figure(title=title, x_axis_label='year', y_axis_label='%')
----> 4     p.line(x.squeeze(), gdp_change.squeeze(), color="firebrick", line_width=4, legend="% GDP change")
      5     p.line(x.squeeze(), unemployment.squeeze(), line_width=4, legend="% unemployed")
      6     show(p)

AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'squeeze'
```

Comment: You are calling `.squeeze()` on integers and floats.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling a method on a primitive type, like ints and floats. When you pass x=1952, python interprets x as an int, wich is NOT a object. You could try squeeze(x) and squeeze(gdb_change)